# Getting primary ip of node request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Using: https://github.com/request/request

I am making requests to a remote server and I'd like to know what the remote server sees as the IP of the request. I had previously done this with php and curl which would have a primary_ip in the response. I can't seem to find the equivalent in Node request. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: From what I understand from PHP docs, `primary_ip` is the IP-address of the HTTP server you are requesting data from. You can look that up using [`dns.lookup()`](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookup_hostname_options_callback).

Comment: @robertklep From the docs "IP address of the most recent connection" In my experience this will return the PHP servers ip. However if using a proxy, it will return the proxy's ip.

Comment: Let's take a step back: why do you need it?

Comment: @robertklep Heh that is a good way to handle this problem. I would like to confirm which ip the remote server is seeing as the connection.

Comment: I don't know how PHP determines it (given that a request can go through proxies and whatnot, so the IP-address of the machine the client is running on isn't necessarily the IP-address a remove server gets to see), but you could probably use something like [`whatismyip`](https://github.com/kosmasgiannis/whatismyip).